Deep and shallow copy
I have trouble understanding the deep and shallow copy, and how the method .clone() works in Java. Some sources say it creates a shallow copy, others say it's deep.
public class Kopie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(23);

        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2 = (ArrayList<Integer>)list.clone();
        list2.set(3, 287);

        System.out.println(list2.get(3));
        System.out.println(list.get(3));
    }
}

The output of this code is
287
23

and I have no idea why.

Calling .clone() on an ArrayList does in fact result in the creation of a shallow copy of the original list, but since you're not changing the state of any of the objects that either list holds (you can't do this with Integer objects anyway since these are immutable) but rather are changing the reference value that the list item holds, changes to one list will not affect the other.

Try the same code, but use an ArrayList of objects of type Foo, an object that has a single int field, value, that can be changed with a setter method, public void setValue(int value). Then change the value of one of the items in your cloned array list by calling setValue(...) on it, fooList2.get(0).setValue(100);, to see that what I said above is true. But having said all of this, my main recommendation is not to use clone() to copy lists. In fact, it is usually a bad idea to use clone for anything.

what does the documentation say: "Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements themselves are not copied.)" (emphasis added) -- I believe that is more accurate than "Some sources" and "others"

( BTW an Integer has no depth, try with an AtomicInteger and change its content [instead of changing the list]; or add inner lists and change these lists )

OP, does the linked questions/answers fulfills your curiosity.

Yes, definitely! Thank you @HovercraftFullOfEels
